# Pass state to recursively nested component in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, react-redux

I have a component that has children of the same type as the component itself. I can render the children as well but the children can't seem to access their slice of state. I'm using React with Redux

```js
export class Material extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.renderChild = this.renderChild.bind(this)
    this.getNestedItems = this.getNestedItems.bind(this)
  }

  static propTypes = {
    parentId: PropTypes.number,
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    subtext: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    childIds: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number.isRequired),
    fileType: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  // This is where I am having trouble.
  // Shouldn't the props be accessible from state itself?

  renderChild = (id, childId) => (
      <Material key={childId}
        id={childId}
        parentId={id}
        name={name}
        subtext={subtext}
        fileType={fileType}
        />
    )

  getNestedItems = (id, childIds) => {
    console.log("id: " + id)
    console.log("childIds: " + childIds)
    var childItems = []
    for(var i=0; i < childIds.length; i++){
        var child = this.renderChild(id, childIds[i])
        childItems.push(child)
    }
    return childItems
  }

  render(){

    let childItems = []
    if(this.props.childIds){
      childItems = this.getNestedItems(this.props.id, this.props.childIds)
    }

    return(
      <ListItem
        leftAvatar={<Avatar icon={fileType.length === 0 ? <FileFolder /> : <ActionAssignment />} />}
        rightIcon={fileType.length === 0 ? <AddCircle /> : <ActionInfo />}
        primaryText={name}
        secondaryText={subtext}
        initiallyOpen={fileType.length === 0} // fileType is empty if it is a folder
        primaryTogglesNestedList={fileType.length === 0}
        nestedItems={childItems} // one has to pass an array of elements
      />
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    id: ownProps.id,
    name: state.Material[ownProps.id].name,
    subtext: state.Material[ownProps.id].subtext,
    childIds: state.Material[ownProps.id].childIds,
    fileType: state.Material[ownProps.id].fileType,
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(Material)
```

Also, I'm making use of [ListItem from Material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/list) (these are ultimately rendered inside a List component) and my code is heavily influenced from the [tree-view example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/tree-view) in the official redux repo. My state looks like this:

```js
const initialState = {
  0: {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Root',
      subtext: 'Some subtext',
      fileType: '',
      childIds: [1]
    },
  1: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Child',
      subtext: 'Child subtext',
      fileType: 'png',
      childIds: []
    }

}
```

The state shown has the same structure as in the tree-view example

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, if I understand it right, you want these `Material` components to get it's data from the redux store.
If that's what you want to achieve you need to provide access to the redux's store to each one of the `Material`. Basically you need to wrap all of them with the `connect` HOC.
Example:

```
const MaterialContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(Material);
```

And inside the `renderChild` function you would use this `MaterialContainer`.

```
renderChild = (id) => (
  <MaterialContainer key={childId} id={childId} />
)
```

You can see it working here
https://jsbin.com/taquke/edit?js,output

Comment: Yes it works! Your answer made me realize what the mistake was. I had also split my component into a presentational and a container component, but I was rendering the presentational component as a nested child instead of the container.

Comment: This solved the exact same problem for me, thanks. I was curious why it is that this isn't handled by the `mapStateToProps` we already attach to the component.

Though, as I typed the previous sentence I realized this is exactly because we only `mapStateToProps` for export. The recursively nested children are invoking the component function *before* the export, and therefore need a separate application of `mapStateToProps`.