# redux connect when use self component as child component

Tags: redux, react-redux

I found the child component `Element` was not connected when I want to use action in child component.

how to connect it ?

code:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class Element extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    render() {
        let { children } = props.el.children;
        return (
            <div>
                 { children ? 
                     children.map(el => 
                         <Element key={ 'el-' + el.id } el={ el } />
                     )
                     :
                     null
                 }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Element = connect(
    null
    ,
    actions
)(Element);

export default Element;
```

Comment: `Element` renders it self?

Comment: @Sag1v edited.It will render children(same as `Element`).

Comment: it still renders it self. you are inside `Element`'s render function and you are rendering `<Element />`. if you want to just render the children then just do `<div>{this.props.children}</div>` in your `render` function

Comment: solved, please see here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052344/pass-state-to-recursively-nested-component-in-react-redux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052344/pass-state-to-recursively-nested-component-in-react-redux)

Comment: yeah basically the solution was not to let a component render it self and instead create another component wrapper that connects it to redux. when you recursively rendering that way the `connect` only applies for the exported component and that's not the case here as you render the component before you even get to the export section.

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering `<Elemnt />` inside it's own `render` function.

If you just want to pass the children down the `render` function of your `Element` component then just change it to this:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

    class Element extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                     { this.props.children }
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    Element = connect(
        null
        ,
        actions
    )(Element);

    export default Element;
```

Note that the wrapper `<div>` is there because current version of react only allow one top level element in the render body, and `this.props.children` can hold more than one `element`.